# Should I update my openSSL package?

Tags: openssl, patching

[This link](http://thehackernews.com/2015/03/openssl-vulnerabilities-patch.html) talks about the new patches to be released by OpenSSL Foundation very soon.

It says:

> In a mailing list note published last night, Matt Caswell of the
>   OpenSSL Project Team announced that OpenSSL versions 1.0.2a, 1.0.1m,
>   1.0.0r, and 0.9.8zf will be released Thursday.

Does it mean that all the `1.0.0`, `1.0.2` and `0.9.8` versions has to be updated? Our openssl version is 1.0.1. Should I wait for 1.0.1m to be released and apply the patch?

```
[root@merc07 ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
[root@merc07 ~]#
```

Comment: You should definitely update your OpenSSL package.

Comment: @raz Thank you. Just wanted to confirm and plan it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is already answer and will be out-dated in hours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should always run the latest version of code (assuming it doesn't break a critical system supported by an earlier version, in which case... good luck!).

Answer (score 1):

You're running a version of OpenSSL provided by your Linux distribution. They will provide an update incorporating those security fixes, backported to the version you currently have. All you need to do is to install the updates (e.g. `yum update`) when they become available.